# FTP account ownership on vhost directory makes Apache not run website correctly

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, wordpress, ftp

I've purchased a virtual server, where I'm given of a non-root sudo-enabled user.

Actually I do need to create an FTP account that's not that *sudo-able* account, so I created a no-login account just for that purpose. I've set up VSFTPd correctly, also enabling the "userlist" feature, to specify which user are permitted to use FTP.

Then I created an empty directory under my *sudo-able* account, and I gave ownership permissions to the second account, so to make it more easy to understand, let's say the main account (the one I do use to manage my VPS) is called *ubuntu* and the FTP-user is named *ftpuser*, I created a directory `/home/ubuntu/mywebsite` giving the ownership to *ftpuser:ftpuser*. Then I uploaded a worpdress website, whose default permissions are 755 and 644. The issue is that Apache is not given of any privilege to run the website.

How can I make the website run properly, and which is the most secure?

Should I run that virtualhost with another user (if it's possible)?
Should I force the FTP user to use the www-data group (if that's possible) and run with permissions like 775 and 664?

How can I solve this issue? Any help is appreciated, I'd like to run it using the default permissions, so any update won't break up anything (because of permissions reset).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give apache user the privilege to access your wordpress site give,

> chown -R apache:apache **your-wordpress-directory**

Also ensure that you have placed the wordpress directory in a well known WEB folder like
**/var/www/html/** before executing the above command.

Don't forget to check your **webserver is running or not**.

Comment: Thanks, I mark this as accepted, by the way I set ownership to be ftpuser:www-data changing permissions to include group ownership. The other, very very very easy solution was (on another server) using mpm-itk!